# Android MVP Fragment Presenter to Activity

Tags: android, mvp

I have one `Activity` `(MainActivity)` and a few `Fragments`.
In my `MainAcIivity` I have a `BottomNavigationView`. I need to manipulate the `BottomNavigationView` from one of the `Fragment` `Presenters`. What is the best approach to do this? 
I really don't want to do something anti-pattern.
I searched a lot and didn't find a case like mine. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: IMO having control of the `BottomNavigationView` in a `Fragment` is already **anti-pattern.**

Comment: The BottomNavigationView is in the MainActivity, but I have a button in Fragment witch must transfer the user to the previous Fragment and manipulate the BottomNavigationView. So my question is, what is the best way to handle this and still have strong MVP.

Comment: I don't really use `BottomNavigationView` a lot, but if there is an equivalent like in `ViewPager` where you just need a reference of the field and call `setCurrentItem()`. Probably not the best way but its better than having to use interface as a callback.

Comment: Maybe using a LocalBroadcastManager registered in the MainActivity and sending the broadcast when you need to update.